# react-selectize shows no results message as soon as I click into the input field

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-selectize for a simple dropdown search component. I am having one small issue that I can't find a good solution for. When the user first clicks into the input field, the dropdown is set to open and the 'no results found' message is displayed. I have tried to prevent the dropdown from opening before a user has actually searched for something, but when I do, it also disables the focus on the input field and prevents a user from entering anything at all. Is there a good work around for this?